# Review results field

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to post on the form a field that and only a Editors permission user can modify and a none permission user can see, for example the result of a evaluation of a specific document uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that field in its property "Show this field" as "Internally", then, your editor should go and enter cognitoforms.com so he can see or modify that field, without revealing it to your responders.